# parameter type in late-binding

Tags: c#, office-interop, late-binding

I have reached this final step, where i need to invoke the `"PasteAndFormat"` method on the `objContentLateBinded` that I have correctly created, but now I need to pass the "WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting" value as a parameter.
WdRecoveryType is part of the late binded assembly `"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word"`, so how can use it in my code in place of -parameters-?

here is the row in question:

```
objContentLateBinded.GetType().InvokeMember("PasteAndFormat", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, objContentLateBinded, -parameters-);
```

Comment: Just pass an integer, 16.  Doing latebound Word is cruel, unusual and unnecessary punishment.

Comment: I can't agree more... Anyway, your advice did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After applying some reflection you can easily find that the value related to that parameter is 16. Just pass it as an integer, this will do the "magic".